# SSRS Charts displaying time greater than 24 hours

Tags: time, reporting-services, charts

I have a time field in seconds (where the seconds is always greater than 86400) and I've been using the following formula to display the time in **HH:mm:ss** in a Tablix:

```
=Floor(Sum(Fields!SecondsField.Value) / 3600) & ":" & 
       Format(DateAdd("s", Sum(Fields!SecondsField.Value), "00:00"), "mm:ss")
```

When I try to plot this field using a bar chart (and using the same formula for the series formula), no data is displayed and was wondering if you had any ideas how to get around this?

Ideally this time field will be on the Y-axis.